# Linux rename files before directories

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename

I have the following command that I run to lowercase files/directories, replace . with _ and various other manipulations.  The problem with it is that it seems to try to rename the directories first and then it cannot find the files below it. Is there a way to rename all files in a directory first then the directory itself recursively?  e.g.

- directory1

  - file1
  - file2
  - directory1

    - file1
    - file2
  - directory2

    - file1
- directory2

  - file1
  - file2

My code is

```
while IFS= read -rd '' entry; do
   entry="${entry#./}"         # strip ./
   if [[ -d $entry ]]; then
      rename  'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/g; s/sometext//g; s/_extras/-extras/g' "$entry"
   else
      rename  'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/\.(?=.*\.)/_/g; s/ /_/g;  s/_-_/-/g; s/sometext//g; s/_extras/-extras/g' "$entry"
   fi
done < <(find . -iname '*' -print0)
```

Comment: You need to use recursion to achieve that in one shot or rename files only first then the directories

Comment: I'd use `find` to create a list and sort that bottom up regarding directory/file depth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample UNTESTED code using recursion :

```
recurse()
{
for entry in "$1"/*; do
   entry="${entry#./}"         # strip ./
   if [[ -d $entry ]]; then
      recurse $entry
      rename  'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/ /_/g; s/_-_/-/g; s/sometext//g; s/_extras/-extras/g' "$entry"
   else
      rename  'y/A-Z/a-z/; s/\.(?=.*\.)/_/g; s/ /_/g;  s/_-_/-/g; s/sometext//g; s/_extras/-extras/g' "$entry"
   fi
done
}

recurse "/home"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this answer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141243)
 Your scenario is more complicated but it looks like they were dealing with the same difficulty in terms of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something along this line:

```
find /path |awk -F/ '{print NF,$0}' |sort -r -n -k 1 |cut -f2- -d' ' |\
  while IFS= read -rd '' entry; do
    # ...
  done
```

The idea is to prepend each line with the number of `/` and sort reversely according to this field:

> 4 /path/dir1/file1
>   4 /path/dir2/file2
>   3 /path/dir1
>   3 /path/dir2
>   2 /path

Then cut away the first column. This way you can work on the entries bottom up to avoid renaming issues.

Comment: This looks like it should work but when i try to process the files/directories then i get an error saying 'Filename too long:'.  I might add that I'm using bash for Windows (Ubuntu) and running the command on an NTFS disk if that makes any difference

Comment: From where is it coming, rename?

Comment: yea I think so for if i run this it works fine find . |awk -F/ '{print NF,$0}' |sort -r -n -k 1 |cut -f2- -d' ' |\
   entry="${entry#./}"         # strip ./
   if [[ -d $entry ]]; then
      echo $entry
   else
      echo $entry
   fi
  done

Comment: You could split the entry with `dirname` and `basename` like `dirname=$(dirname "$entry")`, then `pushd "$dirname"; rename $rules "$basename"; popd`.